# Website not connected with database on Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (Focal Fossa)?

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, php

I recently acquired a website that runs on `Contao CMS version 3.5.40` which I have to upgrade to the latest Contao version. I am using `Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (Focal Fossa) on VirtualBox 7`, `PHP 5.6` and `MySQL version 5.7`.

First I need to get the website working normally on localhost before I continue to upgrading but I've ran into some issues.

I've imported the needed database and am using the local host. I've added my website to the `/var/www` folder as well as changed the configuration in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` folder to use the `index.php` file as a `root` document.

If I insert some simple html code into the `index.php` file it displays as expected but when I use the original code in `index.php` a white screen displays. I went into the `localconfig.php` (picture below) file inside my `website-system-config` folder and changed the `dbUser`, `dbPass`, `dbDatabase` and `dbHost` to the values that are relevant to me (I found the `dbHost` value with the command `select@@hostname` in `sql`, I've also tried using `localhost` but it does not work).

I've also checked my `/var/log/apache2/error.log` file which held the following text:

```
[Wed Oct 25 09:06:38.169398 2023] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 862] AH00163: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Oct 25 09:06:38.169486 2023] [core:notice] [pid 862] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Oct 25 09:34:34.325199 2023] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 862] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed Oct 25 09:34:48.346371 2023] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 798] AH00163: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Oct 25 09:34:48.347929 2023] [core:notice] [pid 798] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

As well as:

```
  [Wed Oct 25 10:32:38.119631 2023] [:error] [pid 818] [client 10.0.2.15:46862] PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function Contao\\Database\\mysql_connect() in var/www/website-archive/sic-22-06-2023/systems/modules/core/library/Contao/Database/Mysql.php on line 47
```

Does anybody know what the issue is? My guess is that I am not connecting to my database properly? Could it be possible I need a older version of MySQL (meaning I would have to use a different Linux OS)?

Here are some pictures for context:
https://imgur.com/a/BdfkCq4

So as stated:

- I've made sure the server takes the correct file as root document.
- I've made sure the user which is connecting to the db has all privileges.

I also opened the sql db in a normal text editor and inside the first 8 lines say:

```
pypMyAdmin SQL Dump  
version 4.4.15.10  
myadmin.net 
  
Host: localhost  
Generation Time: Jun 22, 2023 at 10:25 AM  
Server version: 5.5.38  
PHP Version: 5.4.30
```

Which again makes me think I am maybe using a too new version of MySQL but I am also using a newer version of PHP (that is because the owners of the website informed me of the PHP version being 5.6 but nothing about the MySQL version).

Comment: @guiverc sorry for the confusion. I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa) downloaded straight from the ubuntu site

Comment: Check the `/var/log/apache2/error.log` and update your question with the error messages.

Comment: @sotirov i've added the error log, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your system is missing the `mysql_connect()` function. You didn't mention it in your post but I suppose you used `ppa:ondrej/php` repository to install the `php5.6`. In this case, installing `php5.6-mysql` package should fix your problem:

```
sudo apt install php5.6-mysql
```

***Warning:*** `mysql_connect()` is officially deprecated as of PHP 5.5 (released June 2013) and has been removed entirely as of PHP 7.0 (released December 2015). So, it is highly recommended to think about upgrading the Contao CMS version you are using.